# Reusable method for column formating

Tags: java, javafx

I have a following method in my javafx applicaiton :

```
columExample.setCellFactory((TableColumn<Person, Person> column) -> {
        return new TableCell<Peson, Person>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Person item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText(item.getPerson_name());
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Now this works ok, how ever, i would like to make this reusable, i have for example model that is Book, and has different getters, then this becomes unusable.

What can i do to make one method, that i could apply for any Model object.

[EDIT]
Just to clarify a bit, i am using fxml files for my GUI, and i am using hibernate together with models that use non property values(though i can switch that since i am just testing);

I build my data in this way ;
i use hql query, that i later add to observable list, and then i place that observable list on tableview;

```
tableview.setItems(someObservableList);
```

and in my initialize method i have

```
 columnX.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("name"));

  @FXML
TableColumn columnX;
```

At this point i have all my columns filled with data. Now the tricky part, all primitive data from my model class are showed ok, but the objecst are showed as to string methods. and thats why i used that method i linked first

```
columExample.setCellFactory((TableColumn<Person, Person> column) -> {
    return new TableCell<Peson, Person>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Person item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null || empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(item.getPerson_name());
            }
        }
    };
});
```

so that i just get person name, and not the whole to string method.

So is there any easy way that i can do this

```
TableColumn<Person, String> columnExample = new TableColumn<>("Name");
columnExample.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getPersonName()));
```

since i cant use this at my current setup, my program just shows error at application startup.(i assume because this creates new tablecolum and i want this to be applied on my current @FXML column).

Cheers

Comment: Why are you using a cell factory in this case, instead of a cell value factory?

Comment: What error is it showing?

Comment: Ok, your answer helped me a lot, error i was getting was some issue with hibernate that solved after i droped tables.Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case you cite, you should really be using a cell value factory:

```
TableColumn<Person, String> columnExample = new TableColumn<>("Name");

columnExample.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getPersonName()));
```

And then the default cell factory will do what you want.

If you implement your model using the [JavaFX property pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107), i.e. you have

```
public class Person {

    private final StringProperty personName = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public StringProperty personNameProperty() {
        return personName ;
    }

    public final String getPersonName() {
        return personNameProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setPersonName(String name) {
        personNameProperty().set(name);
    }
}
```

then this becomes

```
TableColumn<Person, String> columnExample = new TableColumn<>("Name");
columnExample.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().personNameProperty());
```

---

I often use a utility method for creating columns to reduce code. The basic idea is to write a method that parameterizes the things that vary. In the two previous lines, the things that vary according to the column you are creating are:

1. the text for the column (`"Name"`) in the example, and
2. the function that goes from the *row item* (the `Person` instance) to the property containing the value to be displayed.

The first is easy: it's just a `String`. The second is a bit trickier: you can represent this as a `Function<Person, StringProperty>`, and it would be defined as a lambda expression `p -> p.personNameProperty()`, or a method reference `Person::personNameProperty`.

The problem here, of course, is that not every column is going to be in a `TableView` of type `Person`, and not every column is going to have `String` as its type. So we need to parametrize those too. That can be done by defining a *generic method* with two type parameters. We replace `Person` by a type parameter, say `S`, and `String` by a second type parameter, e.g. `T`. Then we are creating a `TableColumn<S,T>`, and we need a `Function<S, Property<T>>`. So the method looks like:

```
private <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String text, Function<S, Property<T>> prop) {
    TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(text);
    col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> prop.apply(cellData.getValue()));
    return col ;
}
```

You can call this with

```
TableColumn<Person, String> columnExample = this.<Person, String>column("Name", Person::personNameProperty);
```

In Java 8, the compiler can infer the generic type of the method (basically, it sees that `Person::personNameProperty` is a `Function<Person, Property<String>>`, and so it infers that `S` is `Person` and `T` is `String`), so you can just do:

```
TableColumn<Person, String> columnExample = column("Name", Person::personNameProperty);
```

I frequently find that with this setup I don't need the column except to pass it to the table, so the code often ends up looking like

```
table.getColumns().add(column("Name", Person::personNameProperty));
```

---

You can use a similar technique if you really do need a method for generating cell factories. The things that vary in your example are:

1. the types of the items in the row, and in the cell
2. a function that gets a `String` from the item in the cell (i.e. from the item passed to the `updateItem(...)` method)

So the first is solved by creating a generic method, `<S,T>` returning a `Callback<TableColumn<S,T>, TableCell<S,T>>`. The second is solved by using a parameter of type `Function<T, String>` that maps the cell item (type `T`) to a `String`:

```
public <S,T> Callback<TableColumn<S,T>, TableCell<S,T>> 
        cellFactory(Function<T, String> textExtractor) {

    return col -> new TableCell<S,T>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty) ;
            if (empty || item == null) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(textExtractor.apply(item));
            }
        }
    };
}
```

and then your original example becomes

```
columnExample.setCellFactory(cellFactory(Person::getPersonName));
```

Finally, if you needed, you could combine all of these ideas. Suppose you have an `Address` class:

```
public class Address {

    private String street ;
    private String city ; 

    // etc etc

    public String shortTextForm() {
        return street+" ,"+city;
    }

    // ...
}
```

and a `Person` class:

```
public class Person {

    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name ;
    }

    public final String getName() {
        return nameProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setName(String name) {
        nameProperty().set(name);
    }

    private final ObjectProperty<Address> address = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public ObjectProperty<Address> addressProperty() {
         return address ;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return addressProperty().get();
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        addressProperty().set(address);
    }

    // other properties...
}
```

Now create a reusable method for creating columns. This one is going to set both a `cellValueFactory` (so it needs a `Function<S,Property<T>>`) and a `cellFactory` (so it needs a `Function<T, String>`):

```
private <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String text, Function<S,Property<T>> prop, 
    Function<T,String> textExtractor) {

    TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(text);
    col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> prop.apply(cellData.getValue()));
    col.setCellFactory(c -> new TableCell<S,T>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty || item == null) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(textExtractor.apply(item));
            }
        }
    });
    return col ;
}
```

and then you just do

```
TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
table.getColumns().add(column("Name", Person::nameProperty, s -> s));
table.getColumns().add(column("Address", Person::addressProperty, Address:shortTextForm));
```

Comment: Thanks for a really good answer James_D, but i could not make this work in my setup, i updated my original question, so if you can please help :)

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing the point here, but if you have proper encapsulation of the person class you might as well work with a PropertyValueFactory. If person_name is the property in the Person class, then

```
columExample.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("person_name"));
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using a lambda expression in place of the (legacy) `PropertyValueFactory` class. `setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().person_nameProperty())` is about the same amount of code, but is quicker to run (there is no reflection), and (most importantly) is it compile-time checkable. The compiler will look for the method, so if you have a typo in the method name the compiler will catch it. With `PropertyValueFactory` you would get a runtime error which you need to track down, which can be much harder.